# a href= (social media) dosn't work in ul / li

Tags: css, html, href, brackets

I'm trying to create a contact page and I'm struggling with the href-tags for social media. When I try to click on it, it doesn't go anywhere or does anything. Anyone know what the issue is?

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #001725;
  color: white;
  
  h4 {
    font-size: 30px;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    text-decoration-style: solid;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
    text-align: right;
}

p {
    margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

/*Links*/
/* unvisited link */
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:link {
    color: slategrey;
}

/* visited link */
a:visited {
    color: powderblue;
}

/* mouse over link */
a:hover {
    color: ghostwhite;
}

/* selected link */
a:active {
    color: hotpink;
}
```

```html
<!--Begin Article: Text-->
 <article class="text_column">
  <h2>CONTACT<br>&amp;SOCIAL MEDIA</h2>

  <p class="text">
    Sawadee kah&excl;
    <br>
    I&apos;d like to show you some information of my working experiance, projects and passion. I hope you&apos;ll get inspired, so let&apos;s have look around <i class="far fa-smile"></i>.
  </p>
  
  <p id="right">
       <ul>
        <li><h4><a href="https://twitter.com/alice_ticha"></a>Twitter <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></h4></li>
        <li><h4><a href="https://www.facebook.com/MadPandaCosplayArt/"></a>Facebook <i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i></h4></li>
        <li><h4><a href="https://www.instagram.com/MadPanda_Cosplay_Art/"></a>Instagram <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></h4></li>
        <li><h4><a href="https://madpandacosplayart.tumblr.com/"></a>Tumblr <i class="fab fa-tumblr-square"></i></h4></li>
    </ul>
     </p>
     </article>
<!--End Article: Text-->
```

(And I'm sorry if the code is super messy, just started coding with brackets.) And thank you for the support in advantage!

Comment: The link text goes *inside* the anchor tag.

Answer (score 4):

You have to set the text (or the tag li) inside the tag a to set the link on the element

```
<a href="https://madpandacosplayart.tumblr.com/">Tumblr</a>
```

By the way, it is the same for your i tags

Comment: An anchor element can not be the parent of an `li` element. You can wrap the contents of the `li` in the anchor though.

Answer (score 0):

Your text needs to be inside of the anchor tags. Since there is nothing inside the anchor tags, it will not render a clickable surface.

Answer (score 0):

```
<li><h4><a href="https://twitter.com/alice_ticha">Twitter</a> <i 
class="fab fa-twitter"></i></h4></li>
```

Close the a tag after the word Twitter

Answer (score 0):

What you have done is

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/alice_ticha">
</a>
Twitter <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
```

but you should wrapp the text by the `href` to have it as a link
like that

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/alice_ticha">
  Twitter <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
</a>
```

```css
    html {
      height: 100%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      background-color: #001725;
      color: white;
      
      h4 {
        font-size: 30px;
        letter-spacing: 5px;
        text-decoration-style: solid;
        margin-top: 1rem;
        margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
        text-align: right;
    }

    p {
        margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
    }

    li {
        list-style-type: none;
    }

    /*Links*/
    /* unvisited link */
    a {
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    a:link {
        color: slategrey;
    }

    /* visited link */
    a:visited {
        color: powderblue;
    }

    /* mouse over link */
    a:hover {
        color: ghostwhite;
    }

    /* selected link */
    a:active {
        color: hotpink;
    }
```

```html
     <article class="text_column">
      <h2>CONTACT<br>&amp;SOCIAL MEDIA</h2>

      <p class="text">
        Sawadee kah&excl;
        <br>
        I&apos;d like to show you some information of my working experiance, projects and passion. I hope you&apos;ll get inspired, so let&apos;s have look around <i class="far fa-smile"></i>.
      </p>
      
      <p id="right">
           <ul>
            <li><h4><a href="https://twitter.com/alice_ticha">Twitter <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></h4></li>
            <li><h4><a href="https://www.facebook.com/MadPandaCosplayArt/">Facebook <i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i></a></h4></li>
            <li><h4><a href="https://www.instagram.com/MadPanda_Cosplay_Art/">Instagram <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></h4></li>
            <li><h4><a href="https://madpandacosplayart.tumblr.com/">Tumblr <i class="fab fa-tumblr-square"></a></i></h4></li>
        </ul>
         </p>
         </article>
```

Answer (score 0):

You mismatch the text

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #001725;
  color: white;
  
  h4 {
    font-size: 30px;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    text-decoration-style: solid;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
    text-align: right;
}

p {
    margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

/*Links*/
/* unvisited link */
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:link {
    color: slategrey;
}

/* visited link */
a:visited {
    color: powderblue;
}

/* mouse over link */
a:hover {
    color: ghostwhite;
}

/* selected link */
a:active {
    color: hotpink;
}
```

```html
<!--Begin Article: Text-->
 <article class="text_column">
  <h2>CONTACT<br>&amp;SOCIAL MEDIA</h2>

  <p class="text">
    Sawadee kah&excl;
    <br>
    I&apos;d like to show you some information of my working experiance, projects and passion. I hope you&apos;ll get inspired, so let&apos;s have look around <i class="far fa-smile"></i>.
  </p>
  
  <p id="right">
       <ul>
        <li><h4><a href="https://twitter.com/alice_ticha">Twitter <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></h4></li>
        <li><h4><a href="https://www.facebook.com/MadPandaCosplayArt/">Facebook <i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i></a></h4></li>
        <li><h4><a href="https://www.instagram.com/MadPanda_Cosplay_Art/">Instagram <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></h4></li>
        <li><h4><a href="https://madpandacosplayart.tumblr.com/">Tumblr <i class="fab fa-tumblr-square"></i></a></h4></li>
    </ul>
     </p>
     </article>
<!--End Article: Text-->
```